# C - Printing whole array, separating between every third element

Tags: c

I am sorry if the title is confusing. Let's suppose I have a character array, made like this:

```
[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,...]
```

And I'd like to print  it's elements out like this:

```
123,456,789
```

using as only funtion `write()`.
I clarify that the last element must not be followed by a comma and that the length of the array is unknown (i set its legth to 1000 but only insered some values in another loop, so we don't know to which point the array is populated but we know that that number is a multiple of 3).

I have tried the following:

```
for (int i=0;i<1000;i+=3){
    write(i,&array,i+3)
}
```

but this only printed the first 3 numbers.

I am sorry if I have not been clear enough, but this is all details I have.

Is this possible?
Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: What exactly is the `write()` function? If you're referring to https://linux.die.net/man/2/write then you need to revise it. Even though it is not the only problem present with your code

Answer (score 1):

First, you should read the documentation of `write()` function. This function takes 3 arguments, in the following order:

- The file descriptor obtained by using `open()`
- The array buffer you want to print (`array` in your case)
- The length in bytes to print from that buffer.

So supposing that you declared your array like this:

```c
char array[1000] = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', ...];
```

you can print 3 elements separated by a comma like this:

```c
int fd = STDOUT_FILENO; // This is 1, but better use named constants

for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i += 3)
{
    write(fd, array + i, 3);
    write(fd, ",", 1)
}
```

This is one option. Please note that this example works on character arrays as you said. If you have integer arrays instead, it is a bit more work to be done, because you have to translate those integers to strings and print every translated number one by one.

Side note: you have 3 files opened by default:

- `0` - standard input - `STDIN_FILENO`
- `1` - standard output - `STDOUT_FILENO`
- `2` - standard error - `STDERR_FILENO`